# Is there another way of breaking lines in html apart from <br />?

Tags: html, line-breaks

I'm building an asp.net application and I'm using a `<br />` element inside one of my `ListItem`s.  This isn't recommended but it works anyway.

Is there another way to break a line in `HTML`? (not `CSS`!)

I use `&nbsp;` alot and other characters like `&close;`.  Is there some equivalent for breaklines using `&<code>` ?

Comment: Absolutely all block level tags will break cause an implicit line break. Whatever, why would a raw line feed character be acceptable where `<br>` isn't?

Comment: "This isn't recommended" — It is under some circumstances. HTML is a language designed to describe the semantics of your content. Sometimes an explicitly line break is semantically appropriate. In order to suggest the correct markup for your content, we need to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "pre" tag to send text aleady breaked. Example:

```
<pre>
LINE 1
LINE 2
LINE 3
</pre>
```

Another option is to use Paragraphs:

```
<p> Line 1 </p>
<p> Line 2 </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs can be surrounded by `<p>` tags.

```
<p>This is my first paragraph.</p>
<!-- a line break will be rendered here -->
<p>This is my second paragraph.</p>
```

If your content is a list, you can markup each list item with `<li>` tags and surround the whole list with either `<ul>` or `<ol>` tags for unordered or ordered lists, respectively. The latter have numbers on the left instead of bullets.

```
<ul>
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>list item 3</li>
</ul>
```

For non-semantic blocks, you can surround content in `<div>` tags.

Comment: Bare in mind that a `<p>` is - as it says - a paragraph. The space between paragraphs is _typographically_ **not** a line break!

Comment: I can't use these tags inside a RadioButtonList

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about short code for new line in html but there are block elements in html. 
A block element takes entire width of container and element after it will be on next line.
for example

```
<p></p> or <div></div>
```

You can also use <pre>, now every new line in editor/code will reflect in browser without any special code or element.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag that does not ignore white space by default is [`<pre>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre):

> The HTML `<pre>` element (or HTML Preformatted Text) represents
>   preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in
>   a non-proportional ("monospace") font exactly as it is laid out in the
>   file. Whitespace inside this element is displayed as typed.

All others would require CSS to do so.